# Using CSS to show/hide an element within an SVG

Tags: css, svg, show-hide

I've got an SVG file with two parts to it. I've managed to create a hover state to change the color of the piece with a class of .segment_1 when I hover over it, (hovering over .segment_1 changes the color, that part works). I also have another element in the same SVG file that I've been able to hide successfully using CSS, (#matter). The problem is that I can't seem to get the div named #matter to also show with the hover state. The color change works but the show state of the div named (#matter) does not. Thanks in advance for any help on this.

```css
.segment_1 {fill:#a1a1a1;}
.segment_1:hover {fill:#F9A92F;}
    
#matter {display: none;}
    
.segment_1:hover #matter {display:block;}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="rocket_x5F_svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
      y="0px" viewBox="0 0 612 792" style="enable-background:new 0 0 612 792;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
     .st0{fill:#E6E7E8;}
     .st1{fill:#F9AA30;}
    </style>
    <g id="rocket">
     <path id="segment_x5F_1" class="st0 segment_1" d="M305.7,12.3c-14.8,21.5-24.6,47.6-34.8,71.1c10.3,23.8,20.3,43.2,35.3,65
      c14.9-21.7,24.4-41.1,34.6-64.5C330.5,60.1,320.8,34,305.7,12.3"/>
    </g>
    <g id="matter">
     <path class="st1" d="M278.4,76.7h-139c-5.4,0-9.9-4.4-9.9-9.9V47.4c0-5.4,4.4-9.9,9.9-9.9h139c5.4,0,9.9,4.4,9.9,9.9v19.4
      C288.2,72.2,283.8,76.7,278.4,76.7z"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Please post your SVG. It is rather hard to debug a file we can't see.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I'm new to the site and wasn't sure how to post the image file, however, here's the link to it. 

![rocket] (http://sciencerockit.com/images/Rocket_Original.svg)

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what you mean by "The problem is that I can't seem to get the second set of elements to show with the hover state."? Which are the second set? "segment_2"?  It would be helpful if you trimmed the SVG down to just the element(s) you are having trouble with and create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also the SVG you posted does not match your CSS. There are no elements with class `segment_1`, `segment_2` etc in your SVG.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I trimmed down the file and edited the question. I hope it makes sense. The line of code that seems to be giving me the problem is .segment_1:hover #matter {display:block;} , but I could be wrong. I'm using a test file for the purpose of this question. It can be found at ![rocket] (sciencerockit.com/images/rocket_test.svg)

Answer (score 2):

> The line of code that seems to be giving me the problem is
>
> ```
> .segment_1:hover #matter {display:block;}
> ```

You are correct. That CSS rule is not going to work.  `.segment_1 #matter` means "the descendant of ".segment_1" which has the id 'matter'".  But "#matter" is not a child. It is the sibling of #matter's parent.

The nearest you can get with pure CSS is apply the hover pseudo-selector to the parent (#rocket) and use the sibling combinator ("+")

```
#rocket:hover + #matter {display:block;}
```

Demoed here:

```css
.segment_1 {fill:#a1a1a1;}
.segment_1:hover {fill:#F9A92F;}
    
#matter {display: none;}
    
#rocket:hover + #matter {display:block;}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="rocket_x5F_svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
      y="0px" viewBox="0 0 612 792" style="enable-background:new 0 0 612 792;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
     .st0{fill:#E6E7E8;}
     .st1{fill:#F9AA30;}
    </style>
    <g id="rocket">
     <path id="segment_x5F_1" class="st0 segment_1" d="M305.7,12.3c-14.8,21.5-24.6,47.6-34.8,71.1c10.3,23.8,20.3,43.2,35.3,65
      c14.9-21.7,24.4-41.1,34.6-64.5C330.5,60.1,320.8,34,305.7,12.3"/>
    </g>
    <g id="matter">
     <path class="st1" d="M278.4,76.7h-139c-5.4,0-9.9-4.4-9.9-9.9V47.4c0-5.4,4.4-9.9,9.9-9.9h139c5.4,0,9.9,4.4,9.9,9.9v19.4
      C288.2,72.2,283.8,76.7,278.4,76.7z"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

This works for your sample, but may not work for your real file.  It'll mean that hovering over any child of the rocket will display the #matter element.

You will probably be able to achieve what you want by rearraging the SVG file so that the rocket part and it's popup are siblings.

```css
.segment_1 {fill:#a1a1a1;}
.segment_1:hover {fill:#F9A92F;}
    
.popup {display: none;}
    
.segment:hover .popup {display:block;}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="rocket_x5F_svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
      y="0px" viewBox="0 0 612 792" style="enable-background:new 0 0 612 792;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
     .st0{fill:#E6E7E8;}
     .st1{fill:#F9AA30;}
    </style>
    <g id="rocket">
        <g class="segment">
         <path id="segment_x5F_1" class="st0" d="M305.7,12.3c-14.8,21.5-24.6,47.6-34.8,71.1c10.3,23.8,20.3,43.2,35.3,65
      c14.9-21.7,24.4-41.1,34.6-64.5C330.5,60.1,320.8,34,305.7,12.3"/>
          <path class="st1 popup" d="M278.4,76.7h-139c-5.4,0-9.9-4.4-9.9-9.9V47.4c0-5.4,4.4-9.9,9.9-9.9h139c5.4,0,9.9,4.4,9.9,9.9v19.4
      C288.2,72.2,283.8,76.7,278.4,76.7z"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

If you are unable to do that, then you will need to resort to Javascript.

Comment: Thank you Paul, rearranging the SVG code worked. I also ending up grouping the different parts and assigning classes to each group. After that it was pretty straight forward and made more sense to me. I also removed the code out of CSS file and put it in the Style tag of the SVG so it all lives together. I doubt that made a difference, but keeping it together definitely made it easier to manage. Thanks again for your help!